Webpack 5 Error - Attempts to Load Default Entrypoint Despite Custom Config w/ Custom Entry Value
In process of updating from Webpack v.4 to v.5.
As the title says, despite the presence of webpack.config.js at root of project, Webpack triggers an error because it is unable to find ./src/index.js.
./src/index.js does not exist and I have specified a custom entry (which Webpack does load).
Any ideas why Webpack is attempting to resolve ./src/index.js when I have specified a custom entry?
Contents of my config file:
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = [
  {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: '/Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src/js/pages/default.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
  },
  {
    stats: 'verbose',
  },
];

I expect Webpack to generate a single file under the default dist directory at the root of the project containing bundle.js.
Instead, Webpack generates bundle.js (containing my entrypoint code) and main.js under dist. Additionally, it throws an error indicating it has been unable to find ./src/index.js.
I've also tried specifying the config file w/i terminal (though it's using the file since it's compiling default.js.
Output of running Webpack (w/ error):
asset bundle.js 1.39 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
./src/js/pages/default.js 137 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.91.0 compiled successfully in 80 ms

PublicPath: auto
asset main.js 667 bytes {main} [compared for emit] (name: main)
Entrypoint main 667 bytes = main.js
chunk {main} (runtime: main) main.js (main) [entry] [rendered]
  > ./src main
  

LOG from webpack.Compiler
<t> make hook: 16.242459 ms
<t> finish make hook: 0.047125 ms
<t> finish compilation: 1.108125 ms
<t> seal compilation: 9.281625 ms
<t> afterCompile hook: 0.032792 ms
<t> emitAssets: 2.9205 ms
<t> emitRecords: 0.047 ms
<t> done hook: 0.09125 ms
<t> beginIdle: 0.016917 ms

LOG from webpack.Compilation
<t> compute affected modules: 0.151791 ms
<t> finish modules: 0.667042 ms
<t> report dependency errors and warnings: 0.012416 ms
<t> optimize dependencies: 0.127792 ms
<t> create chunks: 1.275542 ms
<t> compute affected modules with chunk graph: 0.082084 ms
<t> optimize: 2.055334 ms
    0 modules hashed, 0 from cache (NaN variants per module in average)
<t> module hashing: 0.072875 ms
<t> code generation: 0.185833 ms
<t> runtime requirements.modules: 0.001291 ms
<t> runtime requirements.chunks: 0.108834 ms
<t> runtime requirements.entries: 0.398083 ms
<t> runtime requirements: 0.682208 ms
<t> hashing: initialize hash: 0.024625 ms
<t> hashing: hash errors: 0.005208 ms
<t> hashing: sort chunks: 0.045667 ms
<t> hashing: hash runtime modules: 0.0345 ms
<t> hashing: hash chunks: 1.049667 ms
<t> hashing: hash digest: 0.0395 ms
<t> hashing: process full hash modules: 0.004167 ms
<t> hashing: 1.557125 ms
<t> record hash: 0.020208 ms
<t> module assets: 0.057334 ms
<t> create chunk assets: 2.298542 ms
<t> process assets: 0.139 ms

LOG from webpack.ResolverCachePlugin
    50% really resolved (1 real resolves with 0 cached but invalid, 1 cached valid, 0 concurrent)

LOG from webpack.FlagDependencyExportsPlugin
<t> restore cached provided exports: 0.219125 ms
<t> figure out provided exports: 0.016417 ms
    NaN% of exports of modules have been determined (0 no declared exports, 0 not cached, 0 flagged uncacheable, 0 from cache, 0 from mem cache, 0 additional calculations due to dependencies)
<t> store provided exports into cache: 0.016209 ms

LOG from webpack.SideEffectsFlagPlugin
<t> update dependencies: 0.001625 ms

LOG from webpack.buildChunkGraph
    0 queue items processed (0 blocks)
    0 chunk groups connected
    0 chunk groups processed for merging (0 module sets, 0 forked, 0 + 0 modules forked, 0 + 0 modules merged into fork, 0 resulting modules)
    0 chunk group info updated (0 already connected chunk groups reconnected)
<t> visitModules: 0.546167 ms
<t> connectChunkGroups: 0.040042 ms
<t> cleanup: 0.025125 ms

LOG from webpack.SplitChunksPlugin
<t> prepare: 0.037709 ms
<t> modules: 0.001166 ms
<t> queue: 0.002416 ms
<t> maxSize: 0.037167 ms

LOG from webpack.FileSystemInfo
    1 new snapshots created
    0% root snapshot uncached (0 / 1)
    0% children snapshot uncached (0 / 0)
    0 entries tested
    File info in cache: 10 timestamps 0 hashes 0 timestamp hash combinations
    File timestamp snapshot optimization: 0% (0/2) entries shared via 0 shared snapshots (0 times referenced)
    Directory info in cache: 0 timestamps 0 hashes 0 timestamp hash combinations
    Missing items snapshot optimization: 0% (0/9) entries shared via 0 shared snapshots (0 times referenced)
    Managed items info in cache: 0 items

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site'
resolve './src' in '/Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site'
  using description file: /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/package.json (relative path: ./src)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src is not a file
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        existing directory /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src
          using description file: /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/package.json (relative path: ./src)
            using path: /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src/index
              using description file: /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/package.json (relative path: ./src/index)
                no extension
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src/index doesn't exist
                .js
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src/index.js doesn't exist
                .json
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src/index.json doesn't exist
                .wasm
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/src/index.wasm doesn't exist
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site'
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2094:28
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:895:13
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:332:22
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:509:22
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:151:11
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:767:25
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:979:8
    at /Users/nathanhouse/Development/marketing-site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:1109:5

2024-04-17 11:41:30: webpack 5.91.0 compiled with 1 error in 34 ms (6400485c20b09f7d7a3d)
✨  Done in 0.95s.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Well, I feel dumb, but maybe this question/answer will help someone else making my dumb mistake.
My second object in my module.exports array (i.e. w/ the stats property) was being treated as a second entrypoint. This entrypoint (which lacked an entry property made webpack uses its defaults - /src/index.js - which did not exist).
I should have place the stats property inside my initial configuration object like so:
module.exports = [
    {
      mode: 'development',
      entry: {
        foo: './src/foo.js',
      },
      stats: 'verbose',
    },
];

